# matrix dimensions of multiclass neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, matrix-multiplication

What would be the dimension of my output matrix? There are `(x=150)` training examples with 4 features each. In the hidden layer there are 21 neurons `(w2=(1,21))` and I want to train a 3-class classifier neural network.
How I am doing is:

```
a=x*w=(150,4)(4,21)=(150,21):
b=a*w2=(150,21)(21,3)=(150,3):
```

now the y shape is `(150,3)`, are these correct?

Comment: You want to substract *b-y* but it doesn't make any sens. What is your final goal ? Are you talking about gradient descent ?

Comment: i have figured out my mistake maybe,please tell me if the dimensions are correct.b is my final prediction after passing through softmax function.so obviously i need to to subtract (y-b)to find the loss..@debzsud

Comment: Yes, then it looks good. This holds for fully connected layers.

Comment: It's ok. Simple neural networks.

Comment: It's unclear what type of an answer you're looking for. Your (w2=(1,21)) statement isn't consistent with what's below it. What you have written in the code block is correct, assuming you don't want any biases for your neurons. If I write "yes, what you have is correct", would that answer your question? Or are you looking for something else that you're not asking?

Comment: i forgot to edit it sorry.@RyanStout.yes i am intentionally leaving biases for this time.eventually i will add them once i get this done. i have written my complete code and problem here  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20079/wrong-output-for-neural-network-written-from-scratch if you think you can help please do it.i am struggling with my concepts.